# How to detect android default browser javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, browser, browser-detection

Samsung Gallaxy S2 (Android OS, v2.3.4 (Gingerbread)) comes with default browser, I faced some  CSS realted issued, it has to especially specify the values.  I use the JS lib called http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/ to detect the OS and the browser, here it cant apply directly, it doesnt specify the default browser, if I do a change it affects to others(S3, Nexus ect..),

Please someone can me propose me an option to get this done.

Comment: Do you want to detect the specific browser, or a specific webkit version? Since it's CSS-related, I guess that the problem is not browser-specific, but caused by a Webkit bug.

Comment: I want to find a pre-fix then I can give the CSS for S2+ default browser.

Comment: If your problem still is not solved, I might have an answer. But I need no know: are you trying to target 'droidDroid', Android's own browser? If so, that is also installed on Samsung Galaxy S3, Nexus, etc.